# asp.net web.config error in a certain browser

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am currently making an asp.net web application that can work in Eve Online in-game browser. This app is connected to a database so I wanted to encrypt the web.config file so that the password and username do not end up being in clear text.

I used this method to do so:

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/242_Tips_for_Deploying_ASPNet_Application_in_Production.aspx

It works very well but there is a big problem. While the app runs in normal browsers such as IE or chrome, when I try to run in in-game browser I get an error. I made custom errors off for a bit and checked out where the error happens. The error seems to be directing the encryption tag in web.config. But since I cant reproduce this in any other browser I cant find a solution.

Then I try to run the app without encrypting the web.config file and it ran perfectly even in the in-game browser.

I contacted the developers about this issue and posted on their forums but I couldnt get an answer yet.

Also the app has to work in in-game browser because I can get various information with headers about client through in-game browser which I use as inputs in my app.

So my question here is since the database I use does not have any vital information(not even e-mails) just username and password for simple authentication, can I get away with not encrypting the web.config file?

Thanks.